# Modify form elements based on current select box value in same form?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm writing a custom module and I have a select box in a form with two values, Test and Production.  I want to remove a specific fieldset from the form if Production is selected, and add it back if Test is selected.  Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, you can utilize the `#states` setting.  Information can be found in the [Drupal Forms API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states) as well as in the [drupal_process_states()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7) API where you can see examples and documentation on how you can toggle your fieldset based upon the value of that select box.